# Read maximum heap space at runtime

Tags: java, heap-memory

As we all know, the `java -Xmx` option is used to set the maximum heap space available to a Java program. But is there a way for a Java program to read the value that has been set? Something like `System.getMaximumHeapSpace()` (which does not exist).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433406/how-to-get-the-max-sizes-of-the-heap-and-permgen-from-the-jvm ?

Comment: A non-programmatical way is to run the `jmap` utility available from your JDK. The syntax would be `jmap -heap <pid>`. The field `MaxHeapSize` indicates the `Xmx` value set on that Java process.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is a [`Runtime.maxMemory`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#maxMemory()), which the documentation says will return the maximum amount of memory the Java Virtual Machine will attempt to use, but it is not specific whether it is the maximum heap memory set when launching the JVM.

Just as a test, I wrote the following program:

```
class MaxMemory {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory());
    }
}
```

The results of the execution was the following:

```
C:\coobird\>java -Xmx64m MaxMemory
66650112

C:\coobird\>java -Xmx128m MaxMemory
133234688
```

This is using Java SE 6 version 1.6.0_12 on Windows.

Although the values are close to 64 MB (67,108,864 bytes) and 128 MB (134,217,728 bytes), they aren't exactly so.

Comment: I have tested it and it seems to be the value set by -Xmx. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be close, but not exactly the value.

Comment: Maybe the missing bytes got reserved for PermGen space