# Is it possible to determine system limits (like ulimit does on Linux) in a Java program?

Tags: java

I searched for an existing question/answer on this and didn't find anything.

It's easy enough to use ulimit in a shell script to determine things like the process limit and the max open files limit.

But I cannot be sure that ulimit is available.  If the program (which is written in Java) is run on Windows, it will be started by a cmd script (or possibly a powershell script if we're REALLY ambitious), and ulimit is definitely not going to be available.  I want to do the detection and logging in Java, not the script that starts Java.

Is the information that ulimit provides on Linux available in cross-platform native Java code?

Comment: Heap size is governed by JVM options in addition to ulimits; the heap size limit may be considerably smaller than the OS limit for the session. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992991/read-maximum-heap-space-at-runtime for some details on how to retrieve this limit.

Comment: The question in this link describes a pretty generic approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877271/finding-hard-and-soft-open-file-limits-from-within-jvm-in-linux-ulimit-n-and-u

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a generic API in Java to do this. You always have to call some kind of native OS code to retrieve it. What you **can** do is call different scripts depending on the OS you are running in:

```
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
if ("Unix".equalsIgnoreCase(osName)) { // call a bash script }
else if ("windows".equalsIgnoreCase(osName)) { // call a PowerShell script }
else if // etc.
```

Some libraries, e.g. [Apache Commons Lang3](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/SystemUtils.html), provides wrappers making it easier to determine the current OS, but the gist is as above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was afraid this might be the case.

Since a script (either shell or cmd/powershell depending on the OS) is already being used to run the program, it makes more sense to do it there, rather than running a script that starts Java and then have Java call another script.  At the moment, there's a cmd script for windows.  I think it might be a good idea to learn powershell so that the startup script is more robust.

Comment: FYI, this question is for work on the following issue, and/or it's parent issue:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-6734

Comment: Right, if you already have a script starting the java program, it makes sense to do it there system-dependently, then pass the results in via system properties.